# Is Java hashCode() method a reliable measure of object equality?

Tags: java, compare, hashcode, equality

I am currently working on comparing two complex objects of the same type, with multiple fields consisting of data structures of custom object types. Assuming that none of the custom objects has  overriden the `hashCode()` method, if I compare the hashcodes of every field in the objects, and they will turn out to be the same, do I have a 100% confidence that the content of the compared objects is the same? If not, which method would you recommend to compare two objects, assuming I can't use any external libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely not. You should *only* use `hashCode()` as a first pass - if the hash codes are different, you can assume the objects are unequal. If the hash codes are the same, you should *then* call `equals()` to check for full equality.

Think about it this way: there are only 2<sup>32</sup> possible hash codes. How many possible different objects are there of type `String`, as an example? Far more than that. Therefore *at least two* non-equal strings must share the same hash code.

Eric Lippert [writes well about hash codes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) - admittedly from a .NET viewpoint, but the principles are the same.

Comment: Hi, so do I have to write an equals method for over 70 class fields, with many of them being data structures of custom objects? No other way around it?

Comment: If the two objects to be compared are only considered to be equal if all those 70 fields are equal, then there is absolutely no other way around it. Note that an IDE such as Eclipse can automatically generate a `hashCode` and `equals` method for you.

Comment: So for small object, we don't gain anything from using hashcode ?

Comment: @BlueSky: It's not the size of the object that matters - it's the size of the collection in which you're trying to *find* the object.

Answer (score 2):

No, lack of `hashCode()` collision only means that the objects *could* be identical, it's *never* a guarantee.

The only guarantee is that if the `hashCode()` values are different (and the `hashCode()`/`equals()` implementations are correct), then the objects will **not** be `equal`.

Additionally if your custom types don't have a `hashCode()` implementation, then that value is *entirely useless* for comparing the *content* of the object, because it will be the [`identityHashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't overriden the `hashCode()` method, all of your objects are unequal. By overriding it you provide the logic of the comparison. Remember, if you override hashCode(), you definitely should override `equals()`.
**EDIT:**
there still can be a collisionm of course, but if you didn't override `equal()`, your objects will be compared by reference (an object is equal to itself).

Answer (score 0):

The usual JVM implementation of `Object.hashCode()` is to return the memory address of the object in some format, so this would technically be used for what you want (as no two objects can share the same address).

However, the actual specification of `Object.hashCode()` makes no guarentees and should not be used for this purpose in any sensible or well-written piece of code.

I would suggest using the hashCode and equals builders available in the Apache commons library, or if you really can't use free external libs, just have a look at them for inspiration. The best method to use depends entirely on what "equal" actually means in the context of your application domain though.